# Scala trait function: return instance of derived type

Tags: scala, traits

I have a trait Book that looks like this

```
trait Book{
 val sqlTableName;
 def getAll: Seq[ Book ] = { magicSQLFn( $"SELECT * FROM $sqlTableName" ) }
}
```

I have two derived types:

```
class Fiction extends Book{ val sqlTableName = "fiction" }
class NonFiction extends Book{ val sqlTableName = "nonfiction" );
```

I need to get `Seq[Fiction]` when I call `getAll` on an instance of  `Fiction`, say `fiction1`. I know one way to do would be to do a `.map( _.asInstanceOf[ Fiction ] )`. However, is there a way to avoid this altogether?

Actually, I realize the less wrong way to do would be to be able to define a companion object for `Fiction` that extends `Book` so that I can call `getAll` on that object (as opposed to doing it on an instance), however, in that case, I'm not sure how I'll convert the individual elements in the returned sequence to instances of `Fiction` class because `Fiction` class will no longer derive from `Book`. 
Should I have two differently named `Book` traits? One that is the super of these objects, and the other that is the super class of these classes?

EDIT: @Travis Brown's reply solves my initial problem. If anyone have comments on how to handle this using companion objects and not class instances, that'd be great too!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is more or less the classic use case for [*F*-bounded polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification), which allows you to refer to the specific subtype in methods on the supertype:

```
trait Book[B <: Book[B]] {
  val sqlTableName;
  def getAll: Seq[B] = { magicSQLFn( $"SELECT * FROM $sqlTableName" ) }
}

class Fiction extends Book[Fiction] { val sqlTableName = "fiction" }
class NonFiction extends Book[NonFiction] { val sqlTableName = "nonfiction" )
```

(This assumes that your `magicSQLFn` will return something with the appropriate static type, but it is magic, after all.)

*F*-bounded polymorphism [has its detractors](http://logji.blogspot.com/2012/11/f-bounded-type-polymorphism-give-up-now.html), and there are issues to watch out for, but it's a fairly widely used pattern in both Scala and Java.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any comments on how to handle this by calling getAll on the companion object and not on the class instance?

Comment: Not sure I understand why defining `getAll` on the `Fiction` companion object means `Fiction` can't extends `Book`? It's probably worth a follow-up question.

Comment: `[B <: Book]` should be `[B <: Book[B]]`

Comment: Something about being able to do that makes me feel icky. Also happy that I can solve my problem